# Are arrays of pointers indexed on parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

Can I store pointers as arrays and then query them efficiently?

I have a `memberOf` columns on my `Person` object which denotes which `Groups` they are part of. Then I want to query it back who is a member of this group. Will that query be indexed? Comparing its speed to the other queries, it seems much slower and more prone to timeouts than any of my others.

The code is simple:

```
var group = new Group({objectId: request.params.groupId});
var memberQuery = new Parse.Query(Person);
memberQuery.equalTo('memberOf', group);
```

and on the wire it comes out something like this:

`curl 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Person' --data-binary '{"where":{"memberOf":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Group","objectId":"__"}},"_method":"GET","_ApplicationId":"__","_MasterKey":"__","_ClientVersion":"js1.4.2","_InstallationId":"__","_SessionToken":"__"}' --compressed`

Comment: According to what I understand, wouldn't a ParseRelation be more suited to what you're trying to do? As for arrays, the bigger they get, the slower the query gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to a friend who works at Parse, yes, this is supposed to work, but their indexer hadn't found my query pattern yet. They fixed it and now the query is blazingly fast.